# What is the default scope for a spring controller component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I'm diving into the spring bean scopes and application contexts topics and try to understand some concepts.

I understood that there is three main contexts. ApplicationContext (which is the context for a standalone app), WebApplicationContext for web based app (that extends ApplicationContext) and ServletContext (that is not Spring Related but a JEE thing, also related to web applications).

a WebApplicationContext contains all the Web related beans (controllers, ViewResolver etc ....), extends an ApplicationContext and reference a ServletContext

an ApplicationContext contains beans with singleton and prototype scope and
a WebApplicationContext adds three scopes : request, session, websocket and application but application scoped beans are related to the ServletContext referenced in the WebApplicationContext.

What I'm not sure to understand is :

- if controller components are contained in the WebApplicationContext, what is their default scope ? I thought it was singleton but in this case it makes no sense because the WebApplicationContext that contains those beans dies when the server is shut down
- the documentation says that application scope is *"somewhat similar to a Spring singleton bean but differs in two important ways: It is a singleton per ServletContext, not per Spring ApplicationContext (for which there may be **several in any given web application**), and it is actually exposed and therefore visible as a ServletContext attribute."* Its clear, but I do not understand how we can have multiple servletContext for one applicationContext, I didn't find any use case for that. I've seen a usecase for multiple WebApplicationContext in the same app, like an app whith a REST API and a web front, but in this case, there is only one applicationContext and (I thought) only one servletContext shared by multiple WebApplicationContext.

Comment: *the WebApplicationContext that contains those beans dies when the server is shut down* What, exactly, is your understanding of what singleton scope means? Singleton generally (and here) means only that there's exactly one copy running in any particular instance of the application, so shutting down the application (or the server it's running in; these days those tend to be 1–1) destroys the singleton.

Comment: *What is the default scope for a spring controller component?* - Singleton, *I understood that there is three main contexts.* nah you have only 1 app context which might be any of those but it is always one instance of running app (and running app is a "context")

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic  thanks for your reply, so the Application scope seems more appropriate

Comment: The `ServletContext` is the shared thing in which you can stuff things needed to be shared for your application in its whole (the war archive). Each `DispatcherServlet` has its own application context, and generally you have a `ContextLoaderListener` as well to laod the shared beans (datasource, services etc.). All these aplication contexts are a `WebAplicationContext` as they are running as part of an web application. It has nothing to do with the fact that it only contains web related stuff.

Comment: In modern applications (Spring Boot, embedded container) there's usually only a single context layer anyway. I've been programming with Spring since version 3.0 and have not thought about context hierarchies in about 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a conflict between that Controller scope being a Singleton and the WebApplicationContext that contains those beans dies when the server is shut down,
for the controller scope being a **Singleton** this means that the **FactoryBeans** creates one and only one istance of this controller and use it whenever it's called.